# Music Plays and Stops with messages on ImageButtons' Clicks

Tags: android-mediaplayer, imagebutton

Trying to code a simple programme. Four ImageButtons, any once clicked, a particular music plays with a message display; again any button clicked, the music stopped along with a message display again. The problem is that the first click to start and second click to stop performs perfectly; the problem arises when I press any button, this message displays: “Unfortunately the programme has stopped” or something like that and the program crashes.

```
package com.example.appliedexperimentz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private MediaPlayer mp;
ImageView iv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spaceForAnimation);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animestore);
    }



public void imageButton1(View v) {

    if(mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.release();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Music Stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.firstmusik);
    mp.start();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "First Music!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
public void imageButton2(View v) {

    if(mp.isPlaying()){
    mp.release();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Music Stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.secondmusik);
    mp.start();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Second Music!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
public void imageButton3(View v) {

    if(mp.isPlaying()){
    mp.release();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Music Stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.thirdmusik);
    mp.start();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Third Music!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
public void imageButton4(View v) {

    if(mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.release();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Music Stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fourthmusik);
    mp.start();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fourth Music!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mp.release();
}
}
```

Here go the Logcat errors:

11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  ... 11 more
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.example.appliedexperimentz.MainActivity.imageButton3(MainActivity.java:59)
11-14 23:23:31.943: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  ... 14 more

Answer (score 0):

Change your button click function as follows

```
public void releasePlayer() {
    mp.release();
    mp = null;
}

public void imageButton1(View v) {

    if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
        releasePlayer();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Music Stopped!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.muzika);
        mp.start();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "First Music!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
```

Do the above changes to all the button click events. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot to you again for your kindness and helpfulness. I faced some errors, probably because I changed the codes inside the old programme. Tomorrow I shall create another programme afresh with these codes of yours and certainly let you know the outcome of it. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: You know, I really falling short of words to adorn with apt array of appraisal. You are truly brilliantly intelligent; wish I could receive the slightest of your intellect. Any words can never suffice my gratitude towards you for your kindness towards a novice like me. I just need one favour.. could you please explain what mistakes I was making with my previous codes and why it ran perfectly as you changed it even slightly? Please let me know, unless I would be in complete darkness. Awaiting eagerly. Take Care and Thanks a lot again..

Comment: I want to know one more thing.. what difference would take place if I add try.. catch..? Would it affect the programme in any manner? I want to try it myself first, if it really pose a good effect on the codes.

Comment: Read these two articles to get more information about creating media player.

 [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)
 [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)